# How To Convert From System::String to const Byte*

Tags: c++-cli

Can anybody please let me know how to do the above said conversion 
As RegSetValueEx requires  const BYTE *lpData for the path
To get Present Directory I Use GetCurrentDirectory() ,where the Output is of the type String

Comment: What is a System::String? At least nothing in standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you already use .NET (C++/CLI) then please also use the managed classes for accessing the registry!

Be aware:

- System::String is a managed type!
- RegSetValueEx and GetCurrentyDirectory is a native Win32 API!

Please use always C++/CLI:

- RegSetValueEx ==> [Microsoft::Win32::Registry::SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dwk5axy)
- GetCurrentDirectory ==> [System::Environment::CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory)

If it was not intended to use C++/CLI, then please switch it off in your project settings (General: Common language runtime suppoer: No Common Language Runtime Support"